# How to normalise a date columnin pandas dataframe to the same format

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have a dataframe made from pulling in different excel sheets.

I am trying to normalise the date_time column to just a standard DD/MM/YYY format. Is that possible?

| 1 | DATE | Column 3 | Column 4 | Column 5 | Column 6 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 01/03/2021 00:00 |  |  |  |  |
| 3 | 01/03/2021 00:00 |  |  |  |  |
| 4 | 01/03/2021 00:00 |  |  |  |  |
| 5 | 01/03/2021 00:00 |  |  |  |  |
| 6 | 01/03/2021 00:00 |  |  |  |  |
| ... | ... |  |  |  |  |
| 122350 | 11/24/2022 |  |  |  |  |
| 122351 | 11/24/2022 |  |  |  |  |
| 122352 | 11/24/2022 |  |  |  |  |
| 122353 | 11/24/2022 |  |  |  |  |
| 122354 | 11/24/2022 |  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# example df
df = pd.DataFrame({'DATE': ['01/03/2021 00:00', '01/03/2021 00:00', '01/03/2021 00:00', '01/03/2021 00:00', '01/03/2021 00:00', '11/24/2022', '11/24/2022', '11/24/2022', '11/24/2022', '11/24/2022']})
df['DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DATE'])
df['DATE'] = df['DATE'].dt.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
```

output:

```
> df

         DATE
0  03/01/2021
1  03/01/2021
2  03/01/2021
3  03/01/2021
4  03/01/2021
5  24/11/2022
6  24/11/2022
7  24/11/2022
8  24/11/2022
9  24/11/2022
```

Comment: Instead of your first step I applied pd.to_datetime with dayfirst=True to the whole DATE column as I had over 120k rows but otherwise the solution worked.